# How to import custom fields

Tags: custom-fields

i want to import my own table that contains custom fields and custom fields data.

is  there a wizard that will understand that the first line title  is the custom-fields and that that the data that follow the same row is the data , so i dot have to manually create custom fields?

can i create a csv file with custom fields ( no data just the custom fields) and import it to civi , instead of manualy create each and every one of those ?

Answer (score 2):

Custom Fields are complex and can be used for a variety of things. Having a wizard that will automatically create custom fields from the first line of the import file is not a good idea, at least for most non-expert users.

In your original/unedited question you asked if someone could create the wizard. You are welcome to do that, or commission an extension (by [Core-Team](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) or a [Partner/Contributor](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors)) if you think it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can import custom data, but only after the custom fields have been created.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question - you CAN create the custom fields by a CSV file by using either the [command-line API CSV import tools](https://civicrm.org/blogs/xavier/api_batch_tools) or the [API CSV GUI Import extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui).  However, custom fields are very complicated, and this isn't going to save you time unless you have a couple hundred custom fields.